# Изменить формат даты - PHP

Tags: php, дата

Знающие Люди подскажите пожалуйста.

Из XML получаю дату в таком виде:
**Sun, 17 Apr 2022 22:30:00 +0300**

Как средствами PHP изменить формат даты на такой?
**2022-04-17 22:30:00**

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, что за "+0300", а вообще как-то так

```
$a = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Sun, 17 Apr 2022 22:30:00'));
print($a);
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: это часовой пояс))